# 5 cycle instruction forwarding - MIPS

Tags: mips

Consider the following MIPS instructions:

```
lw r6, 0(r1)
lw r5, 0(r2)
add r5, r5, r6
```

Assume I have full forwarding capabilities. I know that when I produce a value, I only "forward" it to another next instruction right before I consume it. With that being said, am I allowed to forward from write back stage to execute stage? I've only seen write back stage do direct forwarding to decode. 
Consider the following cycle diagram:

```
     C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
lw   F  D  X  M  W     
lw      F  D  X  M  W        
add        F  D  D  X  M  WB
```

**Note:** The second occurence of the decode stage signifies a "stall."

Now, in that diagram, I only get `r5` after the 2nd lw instruction finishes its MEM stage. So, I have to stall decode. But at that point, the first lw instruction has completed WB stage. So in that case, would I forward from write back to decode or forward to execute?

If I forward from writeback to decode, that seems like convention. However, if I forward from write back to execute, that seems to comply the practice of forwarding *right before* you consume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

You shouldn't have to forward from writeback to decode, WB happens in the first half of the cycle and ID in the second.

[image]

<strike>This is the best image I could find on short notice, give me a minute and I will try and find the relevant image from a textbook.</strike> Alright, here are some relevant figures from Patterson & Hennessy (a pretty darn good text on computer organization, focusing on the MIPS architecture. I would recommend you get a copy):

[image]

[image]

In writeback, the register file is written to in the first half of the cycle; in instruction decode, the register file is read from in the second half of the cycle. As I understand it, this text's description of MIPS is fairly accurate. In hardware, this might be implemented with two clocks: the EX/MEM/WB stages would be driven by clock A, and IF/ID would be driven by clock B, 180º degrees out of phase (inverted). Careful design of the logic ensures that IF/ID/WB are "complete" in less than half a clock cycle.

In a simulator, you simply have to update the register file from writeback before decode is executed.

Figures from Patterson & Hennessy, *Computer Organization and Design*, Chapter 4.

Comment: Yes, I know about the write and read in reg file on the same clock cycle. However, if I write to decode early, this could cause problems if something forwards to execute right after.

Comment: You need to arrange your forwarding so that the "newest" value is the one that is forwarded, if there is a situation where multiple stages have a value that could be forwarded. Simply make sure that when there are multiple stages from which a value could be forwarded, you select from the stage with the most recent instruction. Any forwarding overrides the WB->ID, because WB->ID is not a forward, it's just regular operation.